# Degree of $\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_n]$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Milne’s note says that the degree of $\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_n]$, where $p$ is a prime, $p$ doesn’t divide $n$, $\zeta_n$ is the primitive n-th root of unity, is $f$, where $f$ is the smallest integer such that $n$ divides $p^f-1$. Can anyone tell me the reason?

Thank you very much!

Comment: That is also the degree of $\mathbf F_p(\overline{\zeta_n})/\mathbf F_p$ when $n$ is not divisible by $p$, and the $\mathbf Q_p$-conjugates of $\zeta_n$ are its $p$-th power iterates $\zeta_n, \zeta_n^p, \zeta_n^{p^2}, \ldots$ (this is from Hensel's lemma, since $x^n - 1$ is separable in characteristic $p$). In short, the situation in the $p$-adics can be regarded as a "lifting" of the situation mod $p$.

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand why the conjugates are its $p$-th power iterates?

Comment: Read about unramified extensions of $\mathbf Q_p$.

Comment: Ohh I see. Thanks!